# how to parse a text file in ruby and remove the tab and new line

Tags: ruby

how to parse the textfile like

```
name   id
name   id
```

and save in an array of arrays in ruby.

So far i have:

```
content = []
File.open("my/file/path", "r").each_line do |line|
    person << line.chop
end
```

It gives the output as:

```
"name\tID", "name2\tID" ....
```

Comment: Couldn't you just split on the tab and move the values into whatever structure you want?

Comment: Don't [`chop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chop), use [`chomp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp) instead, or better, use [`rstrip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rstrip), or [`strip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip) if there's a chance of leading whitespace. `chop` blindly removes the last character of the string, whether its a whitespace or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
content = []
File.open("my/file/path", "r").each_line do |line|
   person << line.chop.split("\t")
end
```

EDIT: to create separate arrays do this:

```
content = []
persons = []
ids = []
File.open("my/file/path", "r").each_line do |line|
   temp = line.chop.split("\t")
   persons << temp[0]
   ids << temp[1]
end
```

Comment: do I need to use .close method to close the file or its not needed?

Comment: When you add a block to the open, the file is automatically closed at the end of the block. So no, you don't need to.

Comment: how can I add only ID's to separate array ?

Comment: I have added an example solution to the edited problem in my answer

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd solve this:

```
class Person
  attr :name, :id

  def initialize(name, id)
    @name, @id = name.strip, id.strip
  end
end

class << Person
  attr_accessor :file, :separator

  def all
    Array.new.tap do |persons|
      File.foreach file do |line|
        persons.push new *line.split(separator)
      end
    end
  end
end

Person.file = 'my/file/path'
Person.separator = /\t/

persons = Person.all

persons.each do |person|
  puts "#{person.id} => #{person.name}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ruby's [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split)

```
pry(main)> "foo\tbar".split("\t")
=> ["foo", "bar"]
```